# multiple edit columns in telerik radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik-radgrid where I use an editcolumn. For the `edit-column` I use a webusercontrol, I created. This works fine.

But know there should be two editlinks. Depending on which he chooses, i want to show a different usercontrol.

when i create two `GridEditCommandColumns` i get an error, because of two columns with the same id "EditButton"

I don't want to put the whole content of the usercontrols into one and show just the content needed, although this would work. But the controls are quite big and it wouldn't be fine to work with it afterwards.

How can I use two `Edit-Columns` in one radgrid?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out myself

I created a `GridButtonColumn` with the command `Edit`
and a `GridEditCommandColumns` where i assign one of my usercontrols to it.

when it comes to the EditCommand-Event I do following:

```
if (((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Text == "Edit1") //The Title of EditColumn 1
{
    rgCases.MasterTableView.EditFormSettings.UserControlName = "WebUC1.ascx";
}
else
{
    rgCases.MasterTableView.EditFormSettings.UserControlName = "WebUC2.ascx";
}
```